# Inclusion Exclusion with Bitmasking

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

N non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an. We will call a sequence of indexes i1, i2, ..., ik (1 ≤ i1 < i2 < ... < ik ≤ n) a group of size k.

How many groups exists such that `ai1 & ai2 & ... & aik = 0 (1 ≤ k ≤ n).`

Operation x & y denotes bitwise AND operation of two numbers.[Problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/449/problem/D)

Approach:
use inclusion-exclusion principle in this problem.

Let **f(x) be the count of number i where Ai&x = x.**

Let **g(x) be the number of 1 in the binary respresentation of x**. Then the answer equals to .

```
(-1)^g(x)*2^f(x)
```

**Code:**

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<(1<<20);j++) {
            if(0 == (j & (1<<i))) {
                cnt[j | (1<<i)] += cnt[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally:

```
for(int i=0;i<(1<<20);i++) {
        int mask = 20 % 2;
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++) if(i & (1<<j)) mask ^= 1;

        if(mask == 0) ret = (ret + pows[cnt[i]]) % MOD;
        else ret = (ret + MOD - pows[cnt[i]]) % MOD;
    }
```

Why This Thing  `cnt[j | (1<<i)] += cnt[j]` and 
How the Second loop is working and How inclusion-exclusion principle is applied is in the last loop. I could not imagine the set formation i.e. How A intersection B is pictured